# Easier way to implement MouseListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have a more general question to ask. 
When I have to implement a MouseListener in my class, the compiler automatically forces me to implement every method there is in a MouseListener interface.
Like so:

```
   MouseListener mouseLtnr = new MouseListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            counter++;

            xs.add(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - getLocationOnScreen().x);
            ys.add(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - getLocationOnScreen().y);

            System.out.println(xs.get(counter-1) + " , " + ys.get(counter-1));

            if(flag == false)
            repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
```

More often than not, I only need one or two of those. Is there a way to implement just the one I need, or do I have to deal with wasted lines of code?
Thank you for your time.
Best,

Dauta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), it is a basic class which implements the `MouseListener` (and `MosueWheelListener` and `MouseMotionListener`) interface, but provides blank implementations of all the methods, meaning you can just override the ones you want...

```
MouseListener mouseLtnr = new MouseAdapter()
{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        counter++;

        xs.add(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - getLocationOnScreen().x);
        ys.add(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - getLocationOnScreen().y);

        System.out.println(xs.get(counter-1) + " , " + ys.get(counter-1));

        if(flag == false)
        repaint();

    }
 }
```

If you dig around the docs a bit, you will find a few more classes like this as well ;)

FYI: `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` will return the mouse cursor position relative to the screen, not the component that generated the event.  You can also use `MouseEvent@getXOnScreen` and `MosueEvent@getYOnScreen` or [`SwingUtilities#convertPointToScreen(Point, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointToScreen(java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component)) depending on your needs ;)

Comment: I upvoted, but I think you meant `MouseAdapter` tho.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Probably :P, Seems my fingers are getting ahead of my brain again :P

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Dauta No worries, it's one of those gems that makes a huge difference in your coding life :)